# how to pass file name to ftp_put function?

Tags: php

It's a simple code to resize an image and send it to ftp server:

```
$info = getimagesize($_FILES["personalPhoto"]["tmp_name"]);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["personalPhoto"]["tmp_name"]);
ob_start();
imagejpeg($image,null, 1);
$resizedImage = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();   


ftp_put($ftpConn,'/Kamil/HostMe/AllImages/'.$fileName.'.jpg',$_FILES["personalPhoto"]["tmp_name"],FTP_BINARY);

ftp_put($ftpConn,'/Kamil/HostMe/AllImages/'.$fileName.'.jpg',$resizedImage,FTP_BINARY);
```

The first ftp_put command works fine (sends the original image to server)

the second ftp_put command which is supposed to send the resized image is not working. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$resizedImage` is a PHP variable, not a physical file. To solve your problem, you can write `$resizedImage` into a file then set this to `ftp_put`. Such as:

```
$file = "/tmp/somefile.jpg";
file_put_contents($file, $resizedImage);
ftp_put(
  $ftpConn,
  '/Kamil/HostMe/AllImages/'.$fileName.'.jpg',
  $file,
  FTP_BINARY
);
```

Comment: It should be file_put_contents